# How can I remap the keyboard in Dawn of War II?

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-ii

From the patch 2.2.0 notes:

> **New Features**
>
> **Global**
>
> - Users can now modify their keybindings, including camera
>   controls, by changing values in the
>   keydefaults.lua file in the Settings
>   folder.  The keydefaults.lua file will
>   not exist until you first launch a
>   multiplayer game after the patch.
>   Please see the contents of
>   keydefaults.lua for more information

But I can't find this Settings folder.

Where is it?  Or is there a better way of changing the key bindings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the original Dawn of War 2 and the Chaos Rising expansion the file to be edited is here: `My Documents\My Games\Dawn of War 2\Settings\_keydefaults.lua`

For the Retribution expansion the file is here: `My Documents\My Games\Dawn of War II - Retribution\Settings\_keydefaults.lua`

Make the edits you want, then rename that to `keydefaults.lua` and it works!